# How to match an array and get the most matched array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to match an array of an array with another array and with the maximum matched array between the two I want to use. but I am unable to get the exact result.I am trying to match the maximum matched and retrieve the result
here is the array of arrays

```
const urlArray = [
        "https://example.com/rating",
        "https://example.com/property",
        "https://example.com/rating/on",
      ];
 const urlArraySplit = urlArray.map((url) => {
            return new URL(url).pathname.split("/");
          });
          console.log(urlArraySplit);//this gives an array of array

const url ='https://example.com/rating/on/45/45'
const array = url.split("/")
```

Comment: what is your expected output in this case?

Comment: @hgb123 expected output is it will match with https://example.com/rating/on because it will match most

Answer (score 0):

```js
const urlArray = [
  "https://example.com/rating",
  "https://example.com/property",
  "https://example.com/rating/on",
];

const url = "https://example.com/rating/on/45/45";
const domain = "example.com";

console.log(findMatch(url, domain));

function findMatch(url, domain) {
  const path = url.substring(domain.length + url.indexOf(domain) + 1, url.length);
  var urlForSearch = "https://" + domain;
  var mostMatch = [];
  const routes = path.split('/');
  for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
    var route = routes[i];
    urlForSearch += `/${route}`;

    var result = urlArray.filter((url) => {
      return url.startsWith(urlForSearch);
    });

    if (result.length > 1) {
      mostMatch = result;
    } 
    else if (result.length === 1) {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return mostMatch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `matchCount` method is get the number matched item between 2 strings.
   Split by '/' and start comparing both array words one by one
2. `closestMatch` method is to over the array of urls, calculate the match count and get the url which has largest match count.

```js
const matchCount = (str1, str2) => {
  let count = 0;
  const arr1 = str1.split("/");
  const arr2 = str2.split("/");
  while (arr1.length > 0 && arr2.length > 0) {
    if (arr1.shift() === arr2.shift()) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
};

const closestMatch = (arr, item) => {
  let matched_str = "";
  let max_matches = 0;
  arr.forEach((str) => {
    const matches = matchCount(item, str);
    if (matches > max_matches) {
      max_matches = matches;
      matched_str = str;
    }
  });
  return matched_str;
};

const urlArray = [
  "https://example.com/rating",
  "https://example.com/property",
  "https://example.com/rating/on",
];

const url = "https://example.com/rating/on/45/45";
console.log(closestMatch(urlArray, url));
```